# Highcharts combine pie chart with a scatter chart

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to combine a pie chart with scatter points in each slice?

for example to display 5 groups of animals in the pie, and plot the individual animal point in the slice ordered by the age of the animal.

I know you could use a donut chart to get close. (http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-donut)

Comment: It is possible to supply a mockup how it should look like in output ?

Comment: something like this: http://imageshack.com/a/img31/8053/eolh.png

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend a [polar](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/polar) or [wind rose](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/polar-wind-rose) chart for that type of data. The reason for that is because a pie chart's radius (the yAxis, if you will) is not actually a measure. Only the percentage of the circumference is of importance in a pie chart.